# In Word 2010, what's the secret to getting captions to appear near the table they're describing?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm working on a document that has 3 columns throughout, with sidebars and tables sprinkled about quite liberally. The layout requirements are really beyond what I think Word was designed to do, but I'm forced to use it in this instance.

I have one table that's causing more trouble than anything else. It's a table that is supposed to span across all three columns. I've created the table and solved the column-spanning issue by having text wrap around the table object. If I don't breathe on it, the layout of the page in question remains intact.

However, I'm trying to add a caption to this table, and when I do it appears exactly how I want it to, but not *where*. It often appears half a page away, or sometimes on a different page entirely.

I've looked for formatting codes (the paragraph symbol button) that indicate some sort of table anchor that I could move to make the caption actually appear next to the table, without luck. I've tried cutting-and-pasting the table to 'reset' where this hypothetical table anchor would be without success. What am I missing? Inline tables that remain within the columns don't behave this way, just the one that needs to span columns.

Comment: It might be easiest to put the table into a text box that spans the columns. Then the caption for the table can go into the text box as well and will remain with the table.